# Change the title in the cmd prompt using batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line

I created a .bat file which executes multiple calls in different command prompt.

```
@echo off
title Start multiple services
start cmd /k Call mongod
start cmd /k Call elasticsearch
timeout /t 5
start cmd /k Call kibana
cd "C:\New folder\influxdb-1.7.6_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.7.8-1\"
start influxd.exe
timeout /t 10
cd "C:\App\App1\bin"
start cmd /k node www
cd "C:\App\App2\server"
start cmd /k node server.js
cd "C:\App\App3\server"
start cmd /k node server.js
cd "C:\App\App4\server"
start cmd /k node server.js
```

the issue what I am facing that for App2, App3 and App4. I am getting the same title "node server.js" in the command prompt which is creating confusion. How could I add different names in the title for these. I tried putting TITLE in the command like `start cmd /k TITLE App3 node server.js`. But that didn't work.

Comment: `Start` already has a `title` option, please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to find out how it works. Also why are you using one cmd.exe instance and permanently opening another seven?

Comment: @Compo, I need to run each application server at a same time (parallelly).  So I had to open a different command prompt for each application. But the issue what I am facing is that app2 is also showing node server as title and app3 also. Do I need to change anything in above commands to run?

Comment: The issue is that I asked you to do something, but instead of doing it, you decided to just ignore that part of my comment.

Comment: As @Compo said, the `start` command has a title option. Use the format `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters] ` [START](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same by

```
START /D C:\App\App2\bin "write your title" cmd /k node server.js
```

For reference check: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html